# Finding limits with Trig Identities

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry

I am having trouble with these two problems.

In the first problem, I would know the answer if there wasn't a $x^2$ in the denominator. I would have performed $\frac{4}{9} \times 0$ and gotten $0$, but I'm not sure what to do since there is an $x^2$.

On the second problem I don't know what to do.

Question 1:
$$\lim \limits_{x \to 0}\ \dfrac{1-\cos(4x)}{9x^2}$$

Question 2:
$$\lim \limits_{x \to \pi}\ \dfrac{\sin x}{x-\pi}$$

Comment: Try formatting your question better with [$\LaTeX$](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 3):

**hint**: $\sin(x) = -\sin(x-\pi), 1-\cos(4x) = 2\sin^2(2x)=8\sin^2(x)\cos^2(x)$

Comment: Thanks I get the 8sin^2(x)cos^2(x) but how do I get rid of the 9x^2

Comment: You can't, but you use $\dfrac{\sin x}{x} \to 1$ fact to go forward...

Comment: question 1 is probably supposed to read $\lim \limits_{x \to 0} \frac{1-\cos(4x) }{9x^2} $ as it stands the limit does not exist

Comment: The problem I am having is trying to solve it. Can someone explain how I'm suppose to solve this.